# using regex matching in c++ to determine if binary

Tags: c++, regex, binary, matching

I am trying to use regex in c++ to determine if a string only contains binary (1/0). I did this in java using .matches("[01]+") quite simply. However now when I'm trying to convert to c++ I'm having issues

I'm using Visual studio 2010 and get this error

Error: no instance of overloaded function "regex_match" matches the argument list

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

// ...

string bFU;
do
{
    cout << "\nEnter a binary value containing up to 16 digits: ";
    getline (cin, bFU);
    if (!regex_match(bFU, "[01]+") || bFU.length()>16)
    {
        cout << "\nError: Invalid binary value.\nTry again.\n"
                "Press Enter to continue ... ";
        bFU = "a";
        cin.ignore(80, '\n');
    }
} while (!regex_match(bFU, "[01]+"));
```

In visual studio I get that error when I mouse over the regex_match which is red underlined

Thanks for the help, I've been googling and sorting through dozens of websites and it just is making the problem even more fuzzy

Comment: Consider [`find_first_not_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of). (Unless this is just academic curiosity).

Comment: No it won't compile still, get a handful of errors surrounding regex_match

Comment: As @BoBTFish implied, a regular expression is overkill here. As is testing each string for a match twice.

Answer (score 1):

`regex_match` takes a `std::basic_regex` rather than a string for the regex.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) for available overloads and usage examples.

Comment: Ok thank you, I made a regex statement 'regex regtest("[01]+");' and used regtest instead of the string I was using. This worked for the if statement but not in the statement of the while loop

Answer (score 0):

If you check a [reference of `regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) you will see that the parameters you pass does not match the ones the function really takes.

See the example in the reference to see how to use the `regex_match` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write your program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const basic_regex<char> binmatcher("[01]+");
   string bFU;
   for (bool matched = false; !matched;)
   {
      cout << "\nEnter a binary value containing up to 16 digits: ";
      getline(cin, bFU);
      matched = regex_match(bFU, binmatcher);
      if (!matched || bFU.length()>16)
      {
         cout << "\nError: Invalid binary value.\nTry again.\n"
            "Press Enter to continue ... ";
         cin.ignore(80, '\n');
      }
   }
   cout << "The binary value I found acceptable was: " << bFU << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't really test this since regex support is broken in g++ 4.7.2.

As you notice, `regex_match` does not take a string. Nor should it. Compiling a regular expression is generally significantly more compute intensive than using one.

Perl is so fast because it compiles regular expressions once the first time it encounters them, a step that is hidden from you and leads to surprising results in some situations (like when your expression is generated at runtime).

Here is [documentation for `::std::regex_match`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). The overload you want in this case is overload 6, which takes a `::std::string` and a `::std::basic_regex` as arguments.